# Javascript - function for update object prop

Tags: javascript, function, object

I would like to have function for update element prop. Something like this

```
function updateElement(element, propName, value){
    element[propName] = value;
}
```

and execution will look like:

```
updateElement(item, "name", "foo")
```

And it's working, but I want to pass propName as a function to avoid string: something like this:

```
updateElement(item, x => x.name, "foo");
```

But I'm not sure how implementation of this should lool like, I have something like this but it's not working

```
function updateElement(element, mapFn, value){
    mapFn(element) = value;
}
```

Can you help me?

Edit I would like to have more generic solution, and I want to avoid hardcoded strings, for example I have:

```
let item = {name: 'foo', address: {...}, ...};
```

I would like to invoke my function in that way:

```
updateElement(item, x => x.name, "foo") <- it will update name, or


updateElement(item, x => x.address, newAddress) <- it will change prop of address
```

Comment: Passing callback doesn't make sense but if you want to, you can try `(context, value) => context.name = value`. So instead of `mapFn(element) = value`, you are doing `mapFn(element, value)`

Comment: To be honest, I'm finding it hard to understand your requirement. Passing reference to a function is a bad design as it will produce side-effect.

Comment: Ok, I agree that this will produce side-effect. But I'm just wondering how to achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension to my comment but you can use a callback which has a signature:

> ( object: Object, value: any ) => // Do stuff

Following is an implementation a function that validates and set values to predefined properties.

#### Idea:

- Create a wrapper functions that takes callbacks and returns a processing function.
- Processing function defines the behavior irrespective of object.
- You can call this function on any object and expect the same side-effect.

Benefit of this approach is, you can create generic validator and setter function.

```js
function updateElement(setCallback, validateCallback) {
  return function setValue(object, value) {
    if(!validateCallback || validateCallback(value)) {
      setCallback(object, value)
    } else {
      console.log("Error: Passed value is incorrect");
    }
  }
}

const dummy = {};

const setNameFn = updateElement((context, value) => context.name = value)
const setAgeFn = updateElement((context, value) => context.age = value, (value) => !isNaN(value));

setNameFn(dummy, 'foo');
setAgeFn(dummy, 'bla')
setAgeFn(dummy, 20);

console.log(dummy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass in a function that returns a name?

```
function returnName(){
  return "name";
}
```

Then you can use the function to return the name and do what you want with it:

```
function passFunction(func){
  console.log(func());
}
passFunction(returnName);
```

But why are you passing a function to get a string? You could use an object that has a string inside it and pass the object.

Comment: My goal is to eleminate hardcoded strings form code, so I don't wont this function for return string

Comment: Ahh okay, so where are you getting the string from?

Comment: right now there are hardcoded in function invocation like: updateElement(item, "name", "foo")
But I would like to have some more generic for recursive invocation

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. `x => x.name` will read the value of `x.name` and return it. It's not possible in JS to get a something like a reference or pointer to a single property to change its value. You could probably do something with property descriptors, but that's not going to be simpler than just assigning the property.

Lets look at your examples:

```
updateElement(item, x => x.name, "foo") // <- it will update name, or
updateElement(item, x => x.address, newAddress) // <- it will change prop of address
```

This is is lot of code and indirection for just doing

```
item.name = "foo"
item.address = newAddress
```

I don't really see what advantages an `updateElement` function would provide, maybe you can provide more information about why you want this.

Comment: @Rajesh: Fixed :) Thank you. Brain faster than hands.